# Class "list" containing structure that contains class

Tags: c++, list, class, structure

i'm trying to write dynamically linked list of complex numbers. Basically: I have a class `list` that contains a structure `number` that contains class `complex`. Box in the box in the box. I have problem with referencing the complex number itself (i only have function that adds a node. My code so far:

#### complex.h

```
class complex
    {
    public:   
        float r;
        float i;
    };
```

#### list.h

```
#include "complex.h"
class list

{

public: 
typedef struct number
{
    complex a;

    struct number *next;
}number;

number *number;

public:
        void add(number* number,complex b);
        list();
        ~list();

};
```

#### list.cpp (contains function add, doesn't work)

```
void list::add(number* number, complex b)
{
        number *newo=new number;        

         while (number->next != NULL)         
             { 
             number = number->next;
             }

          newo = malloc (sizeof(number)); 
          newo->a::r = b::r;  
          newo->a::i = b::i; 
          newo->next = NULL;                
          number->next = newo;
```

}

Thanks for help ;)

Comment: May I suggest `std::list<std::complex<float>>`?

Comment: regardless the problem, you should use different name (or at list Capitalization) between class name and instance - `number` in your example.

Comment: Please tell us the actual problem... "doesn't work" is rather unhelpful! What happens? What were you expecting?

Comment: I don't want to use the `std:list`, I'm trying to to this the hard way and learn something. My reference to the complex part of `number` is not correct, I have trouble with this part of the code `newo->a::r = b::r;`

Comment: why `newo` get "new number" and "malloc" ???

Comment: _"My reference to the complex part of number is not correct"_ does not tell us what you are getting, and what you were expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines

```
      newo->a::r = b::r;  
      newo->a::i = b::i;
```

should be

```
      newo->a.r = b.r;  
      newo->a.i = b.i;
```

or even more simply you could write

```
      newo->a = b;
```

Other problems you have are

1) That you allocate the number node twice, once with `new` and once with `malloc`. Only do it once, and use `new`.

2) The number seems to be an uninitialised pointer in your `list` class. This is going to crash you program. Write a constructor for `list` that initialises number to NULL.

3) Thje logic of `list::add` is wrong, even if number is NULL then the first thing you do is `number->next` which will also crash your program.

4) Names are all over the place (as others have pointed out). Try to pick good names for everything, it will help you understand your own code.

Comment: And don't name your instances the same as the types. E.g., replace `number *number;` with `number *my_number;`

Answer (score 0):

change in list.h the member number (which I guess is the beginning of your list to
number *head;

the function `Add` make no sense. I would do it like that:

```
void list::add(complex b)
{
        number *newo = new number;        
        newo->a::r = b.r;  
        newo->a::i = b.i; 
        newo->next = NULL;                

        if(!head)
        {
            //first item
            head = newo;
        }
        else
        {
            number *itr = head;
            while (itr->next != NULL)         
            { 
                itr = itr->next;
            }
            itr->next = newo;
        }
}
```

Comment: NP (-:
_____________________________